The main page does not display for me
Аfter entering the data during registration or login, and clicking the Get started button, the main page should be displayed, but it does not open, but remains on the same screen and in the console I get the following message:
W/System (17379): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(17379): Notifying id token listeners about user ( HbJ3eNQlRCNnrK0Oe8XEh3maixB2 ).
I/flutter (17379): User successfully signed in: rrrr2r@gmail.com
here is the code for the main page:
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 55),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO: Add onPressed logic here if needed
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 10,
                          ),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 15,
                              ),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              hintText: "Search ...",
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO: Add onPressed logic here if needed
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ImagesCircle(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

and when I import a catalog class and add it to:
  Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
     children: [
        ImagesCircle(),
        SizedBox(16),
        CatalogPage()
           ],
       ),

then it is not displayed, below I have inserted the code of the directory itself, just in case:
class CatalogPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sneaker Catalog'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/Adidas.png',
                price: 99.99,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8), // Add some space between items
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/air_max_97.png',
                price: 129.99,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/Asics.png',
                price: 79.99,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8),
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/campus.png',
                price: 129.99,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/IF8181-A.png',
                price: 79.99,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8),
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/reebok-classic-leather-1983-vint.png',
                price: 129.99,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/Reebok.png',
                price: 79.99,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8),
              CatalogItem(
                imagePath: 'assets/images/Adidas3.png',
                price: 129.99,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


There is no prblm in msg in console. Can you add the code where after login you switch to other screen using navigator.
